# Trying to use Caching in C#

Tags: c#, caching

I am trying yo use caching  data as per my  project demands

So i coded below

```
   public static void Add<T>(T o, string key, double Timeout)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert(
            key,
            o,
            null,
            DateTime.Now.AddHours(Timeout),
            System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
    }
```

now , i am calling a  this function like

```
CacheHelper.Add<Employee>(new Employee() { Id = "1", name = "1"  }, "Employee", 10000);
```

By doing above i am  getting Error:

```
"An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'"
```

Comment: My guess is that you don't have a current HttpContext (`HttpContext.Current` is null). Is your code executed in the context of a HTTP request?

Comment: CacheHelper is static class and Add is static  method

Comment: Why aren't you just using a generic cache that isn't bound to `HttpContext`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use this code only in Http request pipeline procees. Otherwise HttpContext.Current will be null.

Answer (score 0):

You need to debug your application. Something is `null` and you need to find out what.

My personal guess goes to `HttpContext.Current` being `null`.